# @XmlElementRef - JAXBElement wrappers for request and response

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I use for my web service request and response XML the same `@XmlElementRef` elements, for example:

request:

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "elementId", namespace = "blah")
private JAXBElement<Long> elementId;
```

response:

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "elementId", namespace = "blah")
private JAXBElement<Long> elementId;
```

I want to instantiate the element in the constructor of the response. How can I do that, just with `new` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following.  The namespace and local name in the `QName` must match those in the `@XmlElementRef` annotation.

```
return new JAXBElement<Long>(new QName("blah", "elementId"), Long.class, longValue);
```